# Automatically recognizing types when using typeclass instances?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm going over some basic typeclass implementations:

```
data Colour = Red | Green | Black

class BasicEquality a where
   isEqual :: a -> a -> Bool

instance BasicEquality Bool where
  isEqual True True    = True
  isEqual False True   = True
  isEqual True False   = True
  isEqual _ _          = False

instance BasicEquality Colour where
  isEqual Red Green    = True
  isEqual _ _          = False

instance BasicEquality Int where
  isEqual 100 100     = True
  isEqual _ _         = False

main = do 
  print $ isEqual Red Green //Output: True
  print $ isEqual 100 100 //Output: Error Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘isEqual’
```

Clearly, this works when I specify `print $ isEqual (100 :: Int) (100 :: Int)`

Why does Haskell implicitly recognise that `Red` and `Green` are `Colours` yet requires me to specifically bind `100` to `Int`?

Comment: "Basic equality" is a pretty strange form of equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Red` etc. are *monomorphic* values, i.e. they have a concrete type

```
Red :: Colour
```

So when `Red` turns up in your code, the compiler knows immediately what type it is, and it can use this information to infer what typeclass instance to use for e.g. `BasicEquality`.

OTOH, numeric literals like `100` have the *polymorphic* type `Num a => a`. The reason is that we want to be able to write

```
Prelude> replicate 3 'q'
"qqq"
```

as well as

```
Prelude> sqrt 3
1.7320508075688772
```

If `3` had simply the type `Int`, the latter would not work, because `sqrt` expects a type of e.g. `Double`. Since numerical literals are actually polymorphic, this doesn't matter.

The trouble in your case is that `isEqual` is *also* polymorphic. There are thus multiple different types the compiler could select. Image you also had

```
instance BasicEquality Integer where
  isEqual 50 1000     = True
  isEqual _ _         = False
```

then `isEqual 100 100` could be interpreted as either `isEqual (100 :: Int) 100` (which is `True`) or `isEqual (100 :: Integer) 100` (which is false).

In practice, this is seldom so much of an issue, because you won't be comparing different numerical *literals* (these are already known, so you could as well simply hard-code the result!) but at most one literal with one variable in your program, and that variable will usually have already a type determined from the context. For instance,

```
*Main> let b = length "foobar"
*Main> isEqual 4 b
False
```

works without any signature.